# Antd Time RangePicker Exclude specific datetimes

Tags: javascript, datepicker, antd

I'm finding it very unclear if what I'm trying to do is possible out of the box with ant design. I have an array of moment ranges:

```
[ {  start: Moment(), end: Moment()  } ... ]
```

And I have a basic picker in a form

```
const { RangePicker } = TimePicker;

<Form.Item name="location-datetime">
  <RangePicker
    showTime={{ format: 'hh:mm A' }}
    format="hh:mm A"
  />
</Form.Item>
```

For my specific case, date dosn't matter because the times that I'll be working with will always be on the same day. My objective is to simply disable any times that are already present in any of the date ranges in my array. So if I have a range from 4am to 10:30 am, I should still be able to a start/end time of 10:45, but not 10:20. The idea is I don't want my users choosing a range that's already "being used".

But I'm not seeing a way to do that without creating my own complex logic, and this really seems like something that would have been figured out at some point before, I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel here.

How can I use `disabledDate` or `disabledTime` to disable these time ranges in my picker?

Comment: Yeah, as far as I can tell it will require some complex logic on your end.  Antd is awful, even there "basic example" is convoluted with spaghetti code and external dependencies...